# Javascript cursor jumping to end of textarea upon regex replacement

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some code to replace any underscores that the user types to a string of 10 underscores. This is a simple regex replacement. Problem is, the cursor is jumping to the end of the textarea after this replacement (in Firefox at least). So, I decided to store the cursor position via selectionStart. See code snippet below.

```
var start = textarea.selectionStart;

if (enteredChar == "_")
{
    var replaced = textarea.value.replace(/_+/g, "__________");

    if (replaced.length <= 255)
    {
        textarea.value = replaced;
        alert("Setting selection range to " + (start + 9) + ", " + (start + 9));
        // Jump to the end of the newly inserted underscore string.
        textarea.setSelectionRange(start + 9, start + 9);
    }
}
```

The above code works fine. The alert is spitting out the proper position and the cursor is subsequently jumping to that position. Problem is, once I remove the alert, it no longer works. Cursor jumps to the end of the textarea. So if I do something like this:

```
INPUT:
ABCDE(insert an underscore here)FGHIJ

EXPECTED RESULT:
ABCDE__________(cursor ends up here)FGHIJ

ACTUAL RESULT:
ABCDE__________FGHIJ(cursor ends up here)
```

Even more bizzare, if I manually type the position (e.g. textarea.setSelectionRange(10, 10)), the cursor moves to that position just fine. How is that possible? Why would it work when passing the literal but not the variable? Alerting the variable shows the expected number. And again, it works WITH the alert but not without it.

Javascript is so weird. :p

Comment: I'm guessing it's setting the position before it's done replacing content? Try a small `setTimeout` on it

Comment: But it's serial execution, isn't it? And that wouldn't explain why passing literals to setSelectionRange works but passing the start variable doesn't.

Comment: It worked for me as is, but I am in chrome. Have you tried `setTimeout(function(){
textarea.setSelectionRange(start + 9, start + 9);
})` like @Shadaez suggested?